# REST proxy for IIS

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

I am looking for a REST Proxy to run on IIS so that an https GET/POST/DELETE etc can be forwarded "as-is" to another REST server for fulfilment, and to return the results as-is also.

I've done a search, but cannot find anything other than people wanting to convert protocols.

What REST proxies are there available for running on IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use this approach?

[Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/)